# LaTeX Formatting - Left Margins for Vocab Words

Tags: marginpar, marginnote, leftmargin

I recently started working with LaTeX. I'm currently using it to take notes from an old math text. I like the formatting here with the vocab word in the left margin before its definition. I was messing with `\marginpar` to get a similar effect, but I am having trouble recreating it. Any suggestions?

[image]

Here is my not so successful attempt. I am less worried about getting my font formatting to work correctly than the margin structure.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{charter}

\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\marginpar{\textbf{Proposition}}\textbf{Definition.} A \emph{proposition}
is an ordinary statement
which one and only one of the words ``true'' or ``false'' can be meaningfully
applied.
\\\\
{\marginpar{\textbf{Open Sentence}} \textbf{Definition.} An \emph{open
sentence} is a statement involving one or more variables which becomes true or
false each time that specific values are given to the variables. These
values must be chosen from a set of numbers that is specified in advance.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of just posting an image of what you want, make a small compilable sample document that shows what you've tried.  `\marginpar` is certainly one approach, so show us the code and explain what's not working for you with it and we can help you with that or suggest alternatives.

Comment: One important thing to understand is if the word/phrase in the margin is conceptually connected directly to the paragraph beside it (as in your example) or whether the word/phrase is just a kind of signpost to the stuff to its right. If the former is always true, then `\marginpar` may not be the best approach; if the latter is true, then it may be.

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn I just updated with the code I've tried. I see the distinction between the two scenarios you've explained. What I'm looking for is to have the keyword in the margin conceptually connected to the paragraph it precedes and have both start on the same line. I've tried adjusting the margin size to fit larger keywords like "open sentence", but it seems to still wrap regardless of size, so it must be another margin area that I'm not widening enough.